# Most efficient way to return+reset member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move-semantics

Whats the most efficient way to implement `GetDeleteObjects` below?

```
class Foo {
public:
  std::vector<Bar> GetDeleteObjects();
private:
  std::vector<Bar> objects_;
}

std::vector<Bar> Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
  std::vector<Bar> result = objects_;
  objects_.clear();
  return result;
}
```

Currently, at least the copy from objects_ to result is executed. Can this be made faster with `std::move`, for example?

Comment: C++14: `return std::exchange(objects_, {});`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could swap the vectors:

```
std::vector<Bar>
Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
  std::vector<Bar> result;
  result.swap(objects_);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: As @Richard Hodges has shown that this solution and the one with `std::move` are equivalent in terms of performance, I would prefer this one as I find it a bit more intuitive. It is worth noting though, that this also resets the capacity of `objects_` back to 0 (using `swap` with an empty vector is the canonical way I know of to reset the capacity), so if you expect that you will be adding a lot of items to `objects_` again you may want to store the capacity first and make sure to `reserve` that space before returning.

Answer (score 18):

You can use move construction for move-aware types like `std::vector<T>`:

```
std::vector<Bar>
Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
     std::vector<Bar> result(std::move(objects_));
     // objects_ left in valid but unspecified state after move
     objects_.clear();

     return result;
}
```

In many implementations, the transfer during the move-constructions most likely already resets the pointers and the call to `clear()` is not needed. However, a moved from object is only guaranteed to be in a valid but unspecified state. Thus, it is, unfortunately, necessary to `clear()`.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work (for any move-aware object)? Usually, moving is used on temporary objects, which will be deleted imminantly, i.e. the only guarantee is that you can destruct them. In your example, you use `clear()` which is defined for `std::vector`, but not general. So, I think your solution works for `std::vector`, but not for *move-aware types* in general (contrary to what you state).

Comment: @Walter: moving works in general to transfer objects. The state of the original does depend on the implementation which may give stronger or weaker guarantees than what the standard C++ library does. For standard  C++ library classes the moved from object is left in a valid but unspecified stated making the `clear()` necessary. For other types a different approach to restore the moved from object to a known state may be necessary. Moving is "usually" used for temporary objects is that the compiler knows implicitly that it can move from these while otherwise it needs to be explicit.

Comment: @Walter: I wouldn't make such an assumption. In the end, I got over the idea that a stray downvote is meaningful. Also, I already got the Carl Fredricksen hat - so I'm not bothered :-)

Comment: For Juan's benefit it's worth mentioning that the important thing is to write correct code that clearly expresses intent. In almost all cases the optimiser will do an excellent job of implementing your intent more efficiently than you could. For example, in all implementations that I use, the code in `clear()` will be optimised away - but it must remain in order for the code to be correct.

Comment: Looking at this: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.ch/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html could your solution be in general faster than the swap based solution, because no temporary is needed?

Comment: @JanRüegg: when the state of the left-behind object can be unspecified, I would expect it to be faster than the `swap()`. When it is necessary to reset the original to a defined value, things gets less clear. Which of these two versions is faster probably needs measurement. Assuming large vectors both move/`clear()` and temporary/`swap()` will be faster than creating a copy to return, though.

Answer (score 12):

The other three answers are correct so there is nothing for me to add here in terms of answering the question, but since the OP is interested in efficiency I compiled up all suggestions in clang with -O3.

There's almost nothing in it between two of the solutions, but the `std::exchange` solution stands out as producing more efficient code on my compiler, with the added advantage that it's idiomatically perfect.

I thought the results were interesting:

given:

```
std::vector<Bar> Foo::GetDeleteObjects1() {
    std::vector<Bar> tmp;
    tmp.swap(objects_);
    return tmp;
}
```

results in:

```
__ZN3Foo17GetDeleteObjects1Ev:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    $0, 8(%rdi)          ; construct tmp's allocator
    movq    $0, (%rdi)           ;... shame this wasn't optimised away
    movups  (%rsi), %xmm0        ; swap
    movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0         ;... but compiler has detected that
    movups  %xmm0, (%rsi)        ;... LHS of swap will always be empty
    movq    16(%rsi), %rax       ;... so redundant fetch of LHS is elided
    movq    %rax, 16(%rdi)
    movq    $0, 16(%rsi)         ;... same here
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

given:

```
std::vector<Bar>
Foo::GetDeleteObjects2() {
    std::vector<Bar> tmp = std::move(objects_);
    objects_.clear();
    return tmp;
}
```

results in:

```
__ZN3Foo17GetDeleteObjects2Ev:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    $0, 8(%rdi)         ; move-construct ... shame about these
    movq    $0, (%rdi)          ; ... redundant zero-writes
    movups  (%rsi), %xmm0       ; ... copy right to left ...
    movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
    movq    16(%rsi), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rdi)
    movq    $0, 16(%rsi)      ; zero out moved-from vector ...
    movq    $0, 8(%rsi)       ; ... happens to be identical to clear()
    movq    $0, (%rsi)        ; ... so clear() is optimised away
    movq    %rdi, %rax    
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

finally, given :

```
std::vector<Bar>
Foo::GetDeleteObjects3() {
    return std::exchange(objects_, {});
}
```

results in a very pleasing:

```
__ZN3Foo17GetDeleteObjects3Ev:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp8:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    $0, (%rdi)            ; move-construct the result
    movq    (%rsi), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rdi)
    movups  8(%rsi), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
    movq    $0, 16(%rsi)          ; zero out the source
    movq    $0, 8(%rsi)
    movq    $0, (%rsi)
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Conclusion:

The std::exchange method is both idiomatically perfect and optimally efficient.

Answer (score 9):

The idiomatic expression would be to use [`std::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) (since C++14):

```
std::vector<Bar> Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
  return std::exchange(objects_, {});
}
```

Note that this assumes that assigning a value-initialized `vector` is equivalent to calling `clear`; this will be the case unless you're using stateful allocators with `propagate_on_container_move_assignment`, in which case you'd want to explicitly reuse the allocator:

```
std::vector<Bar> Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
  return std::exchange(objects_, std::vector<Bar>(objects_.get_allocator()));
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this also produces the most efficient code on clang. I'll update my answer accordingly. upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Updated:
Richard is right. After have a look at definition of [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), it deal with pointer instead of actual value, which is smarter than my thought. So the technique below is obsolete.

Old (obsolete):
You could use pointers

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  std::vector<Bar> GetDeleteObjects();

private:
  std::vector<Bar> objects1_;
  std::vector<Bar> objects2_;

  std::vector<Bar> *currentObjects_;
  std::vector<Bar> *deletedObjects_;
}

Foo::Foo() :
  currentObjects_(&objects1_)
  , deletedObjects_(&objects2_)
{
}

Foo::GetDeleteObjects() {
  deletedObjects_->clear();

  std::swap(currentObjects_, deletedObjects_);

  return *deletedObjects;
}
```

Comment: std::move has made this technique obsolete.